# pycharm| pip | cv2 and opencv install error

Tags: python, pip, pycharm

I am trying to install cv2 and opencv both in pycharm project. I am using python 3.4

I used these commands

```
pip install opencv
```

```
pip install cv2
```

I am getting error

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement cv2 (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for cv2
```

How to fix it

Comment: _How to fix it_ Use the correct package name when installing, which I believe is `opencv-python`.  Why did you think `cv2` was the correct name?

Answer (score -1):

OpenCV (cv2) is typically installed using the following command:

```
pip install opencv-python
```

You can try running this command in your PyCharm project's terminal. If it is not working, you may also need to specify an older version of OpenCV compatible with your Python version. For example:

```
pip install opencv-python==3.4.6.27
```

You need to replace "3.4.6.27" with your python version.After installing, you can import OpenCV in your Python script like this:

```
import cv2
```

This assumes that your Python environment is properly set up in PyCharm.

Comment: "*You need to replace "3.4.6.27" with your python version*" Why would the version number of `opencv-python` necessarily correspond with the version of Python you're using it with? Considering `opencv-python` versions 3.x don't go further than 3.4.x, what would you suggest a user of the latest Python verison (3.12) do? How is anyone using the actual latest versions of `opencv-python` 4.x, when Python 4 doesn't even exist?